# how to count all records that are repeated more than 5 times in a date

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to obtain in a single record grouped by user the total sum of the records that are repeated more than 5 times on a date

This is my query

```
select user_id, answer_date, count(*) as total_mayor_que_5
from items
WHERE items.proyecto_id = 6
  and `estado` IN (1,4)
  AND `liquidada` = 1
  and items.answer_date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' and '2021-12-31'
  and items.user_id = 832
GROUP BY user_id, answer_date
HAVING COUNT(answer_date) >= 5
```

and as result have this

| user_id | answered_date | more_greater_than_5 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 832 | 2021-11-08 | 6 |
| 832 | 2021-11-09 | 6 |
| 833 | 2021-11-09 | 6 |
| 833 | 2021-11-09 | 5 |

I don't want it to show me all those records; instead, I want a total. For example, for the user with id 832, the total would be 12.

This is my structure table items

[image: db structure]

I want something like this

| user_id | total |
| --- | --- |
| 832 | 12 |
| 833 | 11 |

Can somebody help me? Thanks

Comment: What is your DBMS?

Comment: Please post data as text not images and add the desired output to the question.

Comment: @Serg my DBSM is MySQL 5.6(phpmyadmin)

Comment: What is your desired output? If you want to see User 832 and Total of 63, then wrap a query around what you already have.

Comment: @Isolated edit my answer and place above as i want the query output. 
I'm trying to do what you just told me

Comment: "phpmyadmin" is not a DBMS.

Comment: @Luuk sorry, only I only mentioned the interface jeje

Comment: thank you all for your replies, especially Serg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want one more level of grouping

```
select user_id, sum(total_mayor_que_5) total
from (
    select user_id, answer_date, count(*) as total_mayor_que_5
    from items
    WHERE items.proyecto_id = 6
      and `estado` IN (1,4)
      AND `liquidada` = 1
      and items.answer_date BETWEEN '2021-01-01' and '2021-12-31'
      and items.user_id = 832
    GROUP BY user_id, answer_date
    HAVING COUNT(answer_date) >= 5
) t
GROUP BY user_id
order by user_id
```